# android-7.0 debug has stopped

Tags: android, debugging, android-7.0-nougat

I upgrade my Nexus 5x from 6.0 to 7.0, and now I can't debug my app, it always shows "debug has stopped":

the log:

```
Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0x7468636400, GetDebugThread()=0x7468636400) Expected event thread
Runtime aborting...
Aborting thread:
```

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this problem by finding 
`Android Studio->Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Ru`n.
And make the `Enable Instant Run … unselected`.